# xucinet non-zero exit status

Tags: r

I have a trouble in installing xucinet in R.

I dowloaded the tar.gz file from https://www.analyzingsocialnetworksusingr.com/xucinet, and followed the instruction in the website. I am using MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1, and Rstudio 2023.12.1+402 (2023.12.1+402).

Trying to install xucinet (installed blockmodeling), I could see:

```
> install.packages('/Users/home/Desktop/xUCINET_0.0.2.0020.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source')
ERROR: dependencies ‘sna’, ‘FactoMineR’ are not available for package ‘xUCINET’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/xUCINET’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/home/Desktop/xUCINET_0.0.2.0020.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

So, I installed sna and FactoMineR.
Again, there was a problem in FactoMineR that when I call this, I got

```
> library(FactoMineR)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘FactoMineR’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘estimability’
```

Accordingly, when I installed xucinet, the message said:

```
> install.packages('/Users/home/Desktop/xUCINET_0.0.2.0020.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source')
* installing *source* package ‘xUCINET’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘estimability’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘xUCINET’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/xUCINET’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/home/Desktop/xUCINET_0.0.2.0020.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to install `{estimability}`.

I ran into a version problem though (I'm running R 4.2.2), which I solved by downloading version 1.4.1 from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/estimability/estimability_1.4.1.tar.gz. If you're running R more recent than 4.3.0 then you can use version 1.5 of `{estimability}`.

Install using `install.packages()` or `R CMD INSTALL`. To install in terminal:

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/estimability/estimability_1.4.1.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL estimability_1.4.1.tar.gz
```